# Need Better Understanding Action: woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm die-hard .NET guy.  Dabbled in PHP, and I use WordPress only as a casual user for personal blogs and my photography hobby.  But, I guess that exposure was good enough for my boss to ask me to create a WooCommerce Subscription plugin.

Here's the business logic:

Client offers three subscriptions

- 3 months at $x
- 6 months at $x - 10%
- 1 Year at $x - 20%

If a user signs up for a 6 month or 1 year subscription, and then cancels before the 6 months or 1 year is up, the business owner will not *immediately* cancel the subscription.  What he wants to do is instead change the renewal of the subscription from Automatic to Manual, so the customer will keep paying each month until the original subscription term is expired.  (No comments please on this logic. It's not mine.)

So, I am reading and digesting all the docs I can get my hands on, and I have question about this Action: `woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled`

The [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) say:

> Description: This action is triggered after the subscription specified with $subscription has had its status changed.

**First Question:**

What I'm wondering is...  when it says `after the subscription specified with $subscription has had its status changed`... does it mean after the USER changed the status? Or after the actual status has been changed and logged?

In other words, by the time I fire this action, will the status have already been changed? Or will the action happen after the user opts to cancel, but before the status change hits the database?

**Second Question:**

Am I correct in assuming that I can assign my own method to this action that would prevent (or undo) the actual cancellation, and instead just change the renewal type from Automatic to Manual?

Answer (score 1):

[cancel_subscriptions_for_order()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/#section-5) is called when the `woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled` hook is fired. So you could therefore do a `remove_action` and replace it with your own functionality.

You can find this action on the woocommerce-subscriptions Github repo here: [class-wc-subscriptions-manager.php](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-manager.php#L34).